# Why is hook_update not fully taken into account?

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom content entity created with
`public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type)`.
I just added a field to that entity with
- adding a new `$fields['courriel'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')`
- creating hook.install file with

```
function association_update_8101()
{
  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()->applyUpdates();
}
```

Running update.php has indeed added the field to the corresponding database table and I can access it with my code (for example, I store in that field a copy of user->mail.
But when I use CRUD forms for my Entity (i.e. canonical, add-form, edit-form or collection), I don't see the new field.
What did I miss?

[Edit] my hook.install is now:

```
function association_update_8101()
{
  $storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create('email')
    ->setLabel(t('Courriel'))
    ->setDescription(t('The email address of the Personne entity.'))
    ->setDefaultValue('')
    ->setReadOnly(TRUE);
  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('courriel', 'association_personne', 'association_personne', $storage_definition);
}
```

I managed to run again update.php with success (at least with no errors): the table has now the new column (Courriel) but I still don't have my CRUD forms showing 'Courriel'.
Is there anything else I need to add to hook_update_8101 to have that done?

Comment: I think the problem is not in the update function itself, but it's more likely that you have a missing line.

I think you can inspect what drush is doing, "drush entity updates"

Comment: You can check also this link, with the change records. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2554097

Comment: I updated hook_update_8101 (see Edit in my post) but still not having CRUD forms showing 'Courriel' :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was looking at the wrong place.
Once hook_update_8101 executed, I should have updated myEntityListBuilder.php to be consistent.
The other forms (canonical, add-form, edit-form) were effectively updated.